# Scrapy : UNFORMATTABLE OBJECT WRITTEN TO LOG

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm stuck with this log now for 3 days:

```
2014-06-03 11:32:54-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-06-03 11:32:54-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-06-03 11:32:54-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-06-03 11:32:54-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: ImagesPipeline, FilterFieldsPipeline
2014-06-03 11:32:54-0700 [NefsakLaptopSpider] INFO: Spider opened
2014-06-03 11:32:54-0700 [NefsakLaptopSpider] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-06-03 11:32:54-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2014-06-03 11:32:54-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2014-06-03 11:32:56-0700 [NefsakLaptopSpider] UNFORMATTABLE OBJECT WRITTEN TO LOG with fmt 'DEBUG: Crawled (%(status)s) %(request)s (referer: %(referer)s)%(flags)s', MESSAGE LOST
2014-06-03 11:33:54-0700 [NefsakLaptopSpider] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 1 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-06-03 11:34:54-0700 [NefsakLaptopSpider] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
More like the last line... Forever and very slowly
```

The offensive line **4th from bottom**, appears only when I set the logging level in `Scrapy` to **DEBUG**.

Here's the header of my spider:

```
class ScrapyCrawler(CrawlSpider):
  name = "ScrapyCrawler"
  def __init__(self, spiderPath, spiderID, name="ScrapyCrawler", *args, **kwargs):
    super(ScrapyCrawler, self).__init__()
    self.name = name
    self.path = spiderPath
    self.id = spiderID
    self.path_index = 0
    self.favicon_required = kwargs.get("downloadFavicon", True) #the favicon for the scraped site will be added to the first item
    self.favicon_item = None

  def start_requests(self):
    start_path = self.path.pop(0)
    # determine the callback based on next step
    callback = self.parse_intermediate if type(self.path[0]) == URL \
          else self.parse_item_pages
    if type(start_path) == URL:
      start_url = start_path
      request = Request(start_path, callback=callback)
    elif type(start_path) == Form:
      start_url = start_path.url
      request = FormRequest(start_path.url, start_path.data, 
                          callback=callback)

    return [request]

  def parse_intermediate(self, response):
     ...

  def parse_item_pages(self, response):
     ...
```

The thing is, none of the callbacks are called after `start_requests()`.

Here's a **hint**: The first request out of `start_request()` is to a page like `http://www.example.com`. If I change `http` to `https`, this causes a redirect in scrapy and the log changes to this:

```
2014-06-03 12:00:51-0700 [NefsakLaptopSpider] UNFORMATTABLE OBJECT WRITTEN TO LOG with fmt 'DEBUG: Redirecting (%(reason)s) to %(redirected)s from %(request)s', MESSAGE LOST
2014-06-03 12:00:51-0700 [NefsakLaptopSpider] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.nefsak.com/home.php?cat=58> from <GET http://www.nefsak.com/home.php?cat=58&xid_be279=248933808671e852497b0b1b33333a8b>
2014-06-03 12:00:52-0700 [NefsakLaptopSpider] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.nefsak.com/15-17-Screen/> from <GET http://www.nefsak.com/home.php?cat=58>
2014-06-03 12:00:54-0700 [NefsakLaptopSpider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.nefsak.com/15-17-Screen/> (referer: None)
2014-06-03 12:00:54-0700 [NefsakLaptopSpider] ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None, got 'list' in <GET http://www.nefsak.com/15-17-Screen/>
2014-06-03 12:00:56-0700 [NefsakLaptopSpider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.nefsak.com/15-17-Screen/?page=4> (referer: http://www.nefsak.com/15-17-Screen/)
More extracted links and more errors like above, then it finishes, unlike former log
```

As you can see from the last line, the spider has actually gone and extracted a navigation page!. **All By Itself**.(There's a navigation extraction code, but it doesn't get called, as the debugger breakpoints are never reached).

Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce the error outside the project. A similar spider just works!. But not inside the project though.

I'll provide more code if requested.

Thanks, and sorry for the long post.

Comment: Could you show what are the values that are passed to log.msg() in request & referer arguments?. Maybe hooking up a "print request, referer" line before that.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot!. That led me to the solution. It was a stupid mistake in the end.

Comment: As 90% of cases,  once resolve it looks stupid :) .Glad that this helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I had a `URL` class derived from the built-in `str`. It was coded like that:

```
class URL(str):

  def canonicalize(self, parentURL):
    parsed_self = urlparse.urlparse(self)
    if parsed_self.scheme:
      return self[:] #string copy?
    else:
      parsed_parent = urlparse.urlparse(parentURL)
      return urlparse.urljoin(parsed_parent.scheme + "://" + parsed_parent.netloc, self)

  def __str__(self):
    return "<URL : {0} >".format(self)
```

The `__str__` method caused infinite recursion when it was printed or logged, because `format()` called `__str__` again... But the exception was swallowed by `twisted` somehow.
Only when printed the response that the error was shown.

```
def __str__(self):
  return "<URL : " + self + " >" # or use super(URL, self).__str__()
```

:-)